# Parser return strange script

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing

I'm trying to parse [this page](http://www.aliorbank.pl/pl/o_banku/kursy_walut/kursy_walut_aktualne/main). NSLog gives me strange result:

```
Aktualne kursy walut - Alior Bank
if( window.opera ) {
    if ('fast' == history.navigationMode) {
        history.navigationMode = 'automatic';
        location.reload();
    } else {
        history.navigationMode = 'fast';
    }
}
```

What it can be? Is where the right way to parse this page? My working code:

```
NSError * error = nil;
    HTMLParser * parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.aliorbank.pl/pl/o_banku/kursy_walut/kursy_walut_aktualne/main"] error:&error];    
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        parser = nil;
        return 0;
    }
    HTMLNode * bodyNode = [parser doc];

    NSLog(@"parser = %@", [bodyNode allContents]);
```

**Edit**
I want to parse the table with exchange rates values. But when I try to search a table with class "currencyTable" I get nothing. My code:

```
HTMLNode * bodyNode = [parser doc];
HTMLNode *myNode = [bodyNode findChildOfClass:@"currencyTable"];
NSLog(@"table = %@", [myNode allContents]);
```

NSLog gives me "table = ". How can I get this table?

Comment: What is "strange" about the response?

Answer (score 1):

I viewed the source

```
view-source:http://www.aliorbank.pl/pl/o_banku/kursy_walut/kursy_walut_aktualne/main
```

<sup>(open in Chrome)</sup>

of that file and it seems to be only returning the information between tags.

For example, the title tag is:

```
<title>Aktualne kursy walut - Alior Bank</title>
```

and the first part of your response is :

```
Aktualne kursy walut - Alior Bank
```

The next piece of the html source that has any text between tags is this:

```
<script>
if( window.opera ) {
    if ('fast' == history.navigationMode) {
        history.navigationMode = 'automatic';
        location.reload();
    } else {
        history.navigationMode = 'fast';
    }
}
</script>
```

And again, it returns the text in between those tags:

```
 if( window.opera ) {
    if ('fast' == history.navigationMode) {
        history.navigationMode = 'automatic';
        location.reload();
    } else {
        history.navigationMode = 'fast';
    }
}
```

I don't see how this is a "strange" result. Overall, I suppose I have to ask, **What were you expecting?**

### Edit

Have had a look at the example in the documentation, I would try it like this:

```
NSError * error = nil;
HTMLParser * parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.aliorbank.pl/pl/o_banku/kursy_walut/kursy_walut_aktualne/main"] error:&error];    
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    parser = nil;
    return 0;
}
HTMLNode * bodyNode = [parser body];
NSArray *tableNodes = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"input"];

HTMLNode *tableToParse = nil;
for (HTMLNode *tableNode in tableNodes) 
{
    if ([[tableNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"] isEqualToString:@"currencyTable"]) 
    {
         tableToParse = tableNode;
         break;
    }
}

//Proceed to parse this table node in a similar way.
NSLog(@"Table to parse : %@", [tableToParse rawContents]);
```

Be aware that I haven't tested this code, this is written just from the documentation.

Comment: Could you post a link to the library you are using so I can check it's documentation.

Comment: `[inputNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"]` I have an error at this place. What is `inputNode` maybe `tableNode`?

Comment: It should have said tableNode. I ammended

Comment: unfortunately, code is not working :( `Table to parse : (null)`

Comment: Try printing out each intermediate point: `NSLog(@"%@", [bodyNode rawContents]); NSLog(@"%@", tableNodes);` etc to see where the problem starts

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12398/discussion-between-romanhouse-and-james-webster)

Comment: NSLog of tableNodes array shows me what there are 2 tables. but no one with "currencyTable" class name. Can we go to the chat room?